# AngularJS - The ngView disappears when the parent div animates using ngShow

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to animate between two divs when the route changes.

So far it works fine using ng-show and ngAnimate, but the second div contains the ng-view, which immediately disappears once the route changes. How do I wait until the ng-show animation completes before removing the ng-view from the DOM?

Live demo:
http://run.plnkr.co/7RLwUxwfUV4rb2kV/#/

Sample code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZatzKRKAyxUUfgslxum?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are only animating `ng-show` in your CSS, but you're not animating when `ng-view` switches content. You animate `ng-view` with the `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` css classes. You can see an example here: http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/

Comment: I'm still having the same issue, even after adding animation classes to the ngView. http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZatzKRKAyxUUfgslxum?p=preview

Comment: That's because your route for `'/'` doesn't contain a template. When Angular sees that a route doesn't have that, it removes the `ng-view` element from the DOM, and recreates it when a route is hit that has a template.

Comment: I like the idea, but it's still removing the view immediately. http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZatzKRKAyxUUfgslxum?p=preview

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way, now you have two `ng-view`s. Why do you need that? Can't you have all your content inside the one `ng-view` and just animate that?